# How can i play sound with notification in android?

Tags: android

I am new in Android and i try to play sound with notification and it is not working on simulator. Please help me.

```
public class OneShotAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.one_shot_received, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        buildNotification(context);

    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void buildNotification(Context context){
          NotificationManager notificationManager 
          = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
          Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

          Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
          PendingIntent pendingIntent 
          = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

          builder
          .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
          .setContentTitle("ContentTitle")
          .setContentText("ContentText")
          .setContentInfo("ContentInfo")
          .setTicker("Ticker")
          .setLights(0xFFFF0000, 500, 500) //setLights (int argb, int onMs, int offMs)
          .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
          .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.vatshal.VSAlarm/" + R.raw.satinder))
          .setAutoCancel(true);

          Notification notification = builder.build();
          //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.vatshal.VSAlarm/" + R.raw.satinder); 
          //notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

          notificationManager.notify(R.drawable.notification_warning, notification);
         }
}
```

Comment: in Simulator android notifications  sounds wont work.. but in Mobiles it will work automatically will get the sounds.. and it will change depends upon the mobiles.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, I have set path for sound:--  .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.vatshal.VSAlarm/" + R.raw.satinder))  Is it ok??

Comment: if you use the following line you will get default notification sound from mobile      notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

Comment: and also you can set your required file for audio...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you got a sound in your resources

```
try {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context,                 R.raw.sound);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. On previous example i use mediaPlayer but i face multiple sound problem in this case. For example if i use repeating alarm and using MediaPlayer, next sound start playing simultaneously with currently playing sound.

Answer (score 0):

I used

**.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.vatshal.VSAlarm/" + R.raw.satinder))**

is it right syntax to set the audio path with is placed inside the "raw" folder with "satinder" name??